# Can I use a `multiprocessing.Queue` for communication within a process?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm using queues for inter-thread communication.  I'm using `multiprocessing.Queue()` instead of `queue.Queue()` because the `multiprocessing` version exposes an underlying file descriptor which can be waited on with `select.select` - which means I can block waiting for an object in the queue *or* a packet to arrive on a network interface from the same thread.

But when I try to get an object from the queue, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 234, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

Is there a way to do this?  Or am I stuck using `queue.Queue()` and having a separate thread `select.select()` on the sockets and put the results into the queue?

Edit: I think this is the minimal reproducible example:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

class Msg():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

def source():
    queue.put(Msg())

def sink():
    obj = queue.get()
    print("Got")

threading.Thread(target=sink).start()
source()
```

The problem is that the object I'm putting into the queue has a `threading.Lock` object as a field (at several levels of composition deep).

Comment: This is not very clear, at least to me. I am not following where or why `select.select` is used or what code is raising the exception. Is a single thread/process simultaneously waiting for something to either arrive on the queue or on a socket? How about providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, the title of your post is not very descriptive because the answer to the question it raises is "Yes, in general."

Comment: @Booboo - I've updated the question with an MRE.  The `select.select` is a red herring - the issue is the type of object being put into the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `threading.Lock` instances simply cannot be pickled and *pickle* is used to serialize an object that is `put` to a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance. But there is very little value to passing an object to another thread via a `multiprocessing.Queue` since the thread retrieves what becomes a new instance of that object unless creating a copy of the object is part of your goal. So if you do pass the object via a queue, then the lock cannot not be part of the object's state and you need an alternate approach (see below).

**The (much) Longer Answer**

`First, as your error message states` threading.Lock` instances cannot be serialized with *pickle*. This can also easily be demonstrated:

```py
>>> import pickle
>>> import threading
>>> lock = threading.Lock()
>>> serialized_lock = pickle.dumps(lock)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Second, when you put an object to a `threading.Queue` instance, the object is serialized with *pickle* and so you get the above exception.

But while your posting constitutes a minimal, complete example, it does not represent a realistic program that does anything useful. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Let's suppose you were able to serialize a lock and therefore pass an instance of `Msg` via a queue. Presumably the lock is to serialize some code that updates the object's state. But since this is a different instance of `Msg` than the one that was `put` on the queue, the only meaningful use of this lock would be if this `sink` thread created additional threads that operated on this instance. So let's conjecture there is an attribute, `x` that needs to be incremented in multiple threads. This would require a lock since the `+=` operator is not atomic. Since the required lock could not be part of the object's state if being passed via a queue, then you have to separately create the lock. This is just one of many possible approaches:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

class Msg():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def set_lock(self, lock):
        self.lock = lock

    def compute(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.x += 1

def source():
    queue.put(Msg())

def sink():
    msg = queue.get()
    msg.set_lock(threading.Lock())
    t = threading.Thread(target=msg.compute)
    t.start()
    msg.compute()
    t.join()
    print(msg.x)


threading.Thread(target=sink).start()
source()
```

Prints:

```None
2
```

If you are not using a queue for object passing, then there is no problem having the lock as part of the object's initial state:

```py
import queue
import socket
import os
import select
import threading

class PollableQueue(queue.Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Create a pair of connected sockets
        if os.name == 'posix':
            self._putsocket, self._getsocket = socket.socketpair()
        else:
            # Compatibility on non-POSIX systems
            server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
            server.listen(1)
            self._putsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self._putsocket.connect(server.getsockname())
            self._getsocket, _ = server.accept()
            server.close()

    def fileno(self):
        return self._getsocket.fileno()

    def put(self, item):
        super().put(item)
        self._putsocket.send(b'x')

    def get(self):
        self._getsocket.recv(1)
        return super().get()

class Msg:
    def __init__(self, q, socket):
        # An instance of this class could be passed via a multithreading.Queue
        # A multiprocessing.Lock could also be used but is not
        # necessary if we are doing threading:
        self.lock = threading.Lock() # to be used by some method not shown
        self.q = q
        self.socket = socket

    def consume(self):
        while True:
            can_read, _, _ = select.select([q, read_socket], [], [])
            for r in can_read:
                item = r.get() if isinstance(r, queue.Queue) else r.recv(3).decode()
                print('Got:', item, 'from', type(r))

# Example code that performs polling:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import threading
    import time

    q = PollableQueue()
    write_socket, read_socket = socket.socketpair()
    msg = Msg(q, read_socket)
    t = threading.Thread(target=msg.consume, daemon=True)
    t.start()

    # Feed data to the queues
    q.put('abc')
    write_socket.send(b'cde')
    write_socket.send(b'fgh')
    q.put('ijk')

    # Give consumer time to get all the items:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Prints:

```None
Got: abc from <class '__main__.PollableQueue'>
Got: ijk from <class '__main__.PollableQueue'>
Got: cde from <class 'socket.socket'>
Got: fgh from <class 'socket.socket'>
```

Comment: I tried to sketch out what I'm doing in the question.  I'm developing a module, which runs as part of a larger piece of software.  Its interface with that larger piece of software is a queue.  It also needs to listen for packets on a socket and respond to them.  There is significant shared state between the packet-handling code and the queue-handling code.  A nice design would be to have a single thread monitor both the queue and the sockets but that would require having a queue that I can pass to `select.select`.

Comment: It would be easy to write such a queue in Python 3.10, which has `os.eventfd()`, but unfortunately I'm stuck supporting 3.6.  Might have to start mucking about in ctypes.

Comment: But it's still not clear to me what requires you to pass an object *with a lock attribute* via the queue.

Comment: I have posted an update that shows how you can poll a `queue.Queue` instance and a socket.

Comment: The fact that the message happens to have a lock attribute is not essential to the question; the same problem would come up with any message that's not pickleable.  The lock in my case is somewhat beyond my control as it is part of this module's interface to a much larger piece of software.

Comment: I ended up inheriting from `queue.Queue` in much the way you have in your updated answer, but used Linux's `eventfd` implementation of semaphores instead of sockets and mucking about in ctypes to support `eventfd` in Python 3.6.

Comment: I'm seriously considering a bug report on both the `queue` package and the `threading` package.  Having synchronisation and inter-thread communication primitives that can be waited on as part of a group like this is something I've wanted more than once when writing network code.  But then I tend to use message queues for inter-thread communication somewhat obsessively (and learning golang recently has only made this worse) so maybe it's not something that's so generally useful.

Comment: If you are using multithreading as in my update, then *pickle* is not used and you don't have an issue. Your original problems as I understood it was you were forced to use multiprocessing because you could not poll a `queue.Queue` instance. My update  was to show you how you can poll a `queue.Queue`. `The lock attribute was to show you that including a non-pickleable attribute is not an issue.

Comment: Yep, understood.  Just saying I'm doing something similar but using a different locking mechanism.